# Does Linq.Any() always iterate through the entire list or will it exit upon finding the first match?

Tags: c#, performance, linq, time-complexity

I'm writing a function to check if a string contains at least one of a list of characters.

ex: Does the string `"absegmox;zlkfy"` contain `"f", "m", "t",` or `"u"`

My question is if the Linq.Any functionality will quit when it hits its first match or if it will always iterate through the whole list.

If the latter true than in the average case this:

```
found = characterList.Any(e => myString.Contains(e)));
```

Would get outperformed by this:

```
int i = 0;
while (!found && i < characterList.Count)
{
    string tempChar = characterList[i];

    if (characterList.Contains(tempChar ))
    {
        found = true;
    }
    i++;
}
```

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/concepts/linq/classification-of-standard-query-operators-by-manner-of-execution

Comment: From the documentation itself: **The enumeration of source is stopped as soon as the result can be determined.**

Comment: Your translation of `Any` doesn't reference `myString`...

Comment: @Sach While "Read the documentation" definitely applies here, I assumed you'd be linking to the [`Enumerable.Any` Method](https://learn.microsoft.com/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.any) where it says, as Greg notes, "The enumeration of `source` is stopped as soon as the result can be determined."  Your link, however, talks about immediate vs. deferred execution, which isn't really relevant to the question.  This is a matter of _early exit_ or not, regardless of when execution takes place.

Answer (score 0):

You can always check the .Net source code for [`Any`](https://source.dot.net/System.Linq/a.html#6a1af7c3d17845e3) to validate how it works.

I would suggest a better inline implementation would be:

```
var found = false;

for (int j1 = 0; j1 < characterList.Count; ++j1) {
    if (myString.Contains(characterList[j1])) {
        found = true;
        break;
    }
}
```